# Flutter web Error while loading network image url

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

```
 Future<Uint8List> _loadNetworkImage(String imgname) async {
    try {
      final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9')).load("");
      final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
      return bytes;
    } catch (_) {
      throw "Couldn't resolve network Image.";
    }
  }
```

when i run this code on flutter web i am getting this error i dont know why can anyone please help me.

Error: Couldn't resolve network Image.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
Uint8List fileData = await http.readBytes(uri);
```

Comment: Workeed on web, thanks a lot